# Удалить параметр запроса Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular4, angular-routing

Как сделать переход на страницу текущую, но без одного из параметров? Например из `www.expample.com/home?id=123&pos=sd&sd=iii` сделать `www.expample.com/home?id=123&sd=iii`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На эту тему есть [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18463), и если я всё правильно поняла, то должен работать вот такой вариант:

```
router.navigate(['/'], { 
  queryParams: { hello: 'world' }, queryParamHandling: 'merge' 
}) => /?hello=world

router.navigate(['/'], { 
  queryParams: { hello: null }, queryParamHandling: 'merge' 
} => /
```

Comment: Работает, я сам разобрался, но этот вариант даже проще.